# How to add default authentication "guard" to the auth and configure in Laravel 5.7?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7, laravel-nova

```
Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordBroker::__construct() must implement interface Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\UserProvider, null given, called in /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/Passwords/PasswordBrokerManager.php on line 73
```

Do you have any idea about add  default authentication "guard" to the auth and configure?

Comment: If i want to answer your question. I want some more description about question. What actually you did?

Comment: You are trying to use user object when it is not quite certain `$user` will be filled. Show that code.

Comment: I have already added that passwords configurations but it get auth defaults in config/auth.php file. where do I change to non-default one?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a mis-configuration on your side, please make sure you have the correct configuration in your `config.auth.passwords`, looks like Laravel is unable to create the provider assigned.

More details check: [sample](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/21064)

Comment: I have already added that passwords configurations but it get auth defaults in config/auth.php file. where do I change to non-default one?  @Senthur